# Lorentz transformation of four-momentum from stress tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

For QFT on Minkowski spacetime,
we expect the four-momentum operator under Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ satisfies:
\begin{eqnarray}
U(\Lambda)^{-1}\hat{P}^\mu U(\Lambda)=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu\hat{P}^\nu.
\end{eqnarray}
I want to derive this transformation rule from the relation between four-momentum and stress tensor:
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{P}^\mu=\int d\vec{x}\hat{T}^{0\mu}(t,\vec{x}),
\end{eqnarray}
and the Lorentz transformation rule of $T^{0\mu}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
U(\Lambda)^{-1}\hat{T}^{0\mu}(x)U(\Lambda)=\Lambda^0{}_\alpha\Lambda^\mu{}_\beta \hat{T}^{\alpha\beta}(\Lambda^{-1}x).
\end{eqnarray}
How could we derive the first equation from the lower two?